# Install sqlpackage and azureps on ubuntu Azure DevOps agent

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My Azure DevOps pipeline needs `azureps` and `sqlpackage` in order to run. I am using private ubuntu 18.04 build agent.

I am unable to satisfy these two requirements. I started with installing Azure Powershell adding definition in Dockerfile:

```
RUN wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb &&\
    dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb &&\
    apt-get update &&\
    add-apt-repository universe &&\
    apt-get install -y powershell &&\
    pwsh -c 'Install-Module -Name Az -Force' &&\
    pwsh -c 'Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force'
```

However I still get this error:
`##[error]No agent found in pool my-pool which satisfies the specified demands: azureps, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.182.1` when running the pipeline.

Also I tried installing the `sqlpackage`, however with no sucess:

```
RUN wget -q https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/2/0/020aa2fa-f3f2-41ba-bacd-ff15557890d3/sqlpackage-linux-x64-en-US-15.0.5084.2.zip 
RUN cd ~ \
    && mkdir sqlpackage \
    && unzip sqlpackage-linux-x64-en-US-15.0.5084.2.zip -d ~/sqlpackage \
    && echo "export PATH=\"\$PATH:$HOME/sqlpackage\"" >> ~/.bashrc \
    && chmod a+x ~/sqlpackage/sqlpackage \
    && source ~/.bashrc \
    && apt-get install libunwind8 \
    && apt-get install libicu60
```

In this case I am getting error straight away - 'unzip could not find file sqlpackage-....'.

I am really lost. I spent already an ages on these issues. Any hints, please?

Comment: Hi, not sure if the initial part of the error is indicating an error with your devops agent installed on the vm. If that's the case, you might want to consider installing the "Azure Pipelines Agent" extension on your VM, it does all the required configuration for you. That's the doc: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/howto-provision-deployment-group-agents?view=azure-devops#install-the-azure-pipelines-agent-azure-vm-extension
I also faced the issue with the sqlpackage not found, but it was on Windows, I fixed it by adding to the env. variables.

Comment: Not sure, because when I do not use azure powershell and sqlpackage in the pipeline, it runs correctly using the same VM. So the main issue apparently is that devops pipeline can not see the installed Azure Powershell on the VM.

Comment: I installed this package and got the same error as this. The issue here is that the wget downloads the package somewhere, but you don't specify it.
If you put the line "cd ~" first unzip will find the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of SQLPackage i used Python ([pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15)) and instead of Azure Powershell I used [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt#option-1-install-with-one-command).